# Input binding in function other than Azure Function within the same project

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I have a Visual Studio Azure Function project with number of functions. Most of them need logic calculating some value based on Azure Storage Table entity.

I can easily make input binding to that entity in each Azure Function:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, 
    [Table("Table", "SomeValue", "SomeOtherValue")] MyPoco poco, ILogger log)
{
    // some logic based on poco object
}
```

However this creates redundancy as each function must contain the same logic and table binding. I have created a static method for that logic, but input binding does not work there.

```
public static int DoTheLogic([Table("Table", "SomeValue", "SomeOtherValue")] MyPoco poco)
{
    // some logic based on poco object
    // and return int value to calling Azure Function
}
```

1. Can input binding be done only in functions being Azure Functions?
2. How can I reference to Azure Table in `DoTheLogic` function if the first one is true.
3. Same, could `ILogger log` be used by `DoTheLogic` function?

The only solution I can see is passing `poco` and `log` from each Azure Function to `DoTheLogic` but that does not look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responses based on my opinion:

> Can input binding be done only in functions being Azure Functions?

I believe yes it can only done in Azure functions as Binding is injected `ExtensionConfigContext` by Azure function framework which won't be available in normal functions

> How can I reference to Azure Table in DoTheLogic function if the first one is true.

I agree that passing the `poco` object is right choice which makes your method as pure as it's working on the passes parameters.

> Same, could ILogger log be used by DoTheLogic function?

Yes, ILogger should be used in `DoTheLogic`. However, I would suggest to inject the `ILogger<T>` in the class containing `DoTheLogic` method instead of passing it. With that way you will have segregation of concern. Like as shown in [this](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Core/Implementation/ToDoItemsService.cs) implementation.

Comment: Can you explain why passing `poco` object is the best option while the same time you suggest injecting `ILogger` instead of passing `log` object into `DoTheLogic`?

Comment: Second, can you demonstrate how to inject `ILogger' into `DoTheLogic`. All in the context of Azure Function project.

Comment: Logging is a cross cutting concern and it's not a requirement of `DoTheLogic` method to accept it as parameter and work over that to compute something. Consider a scenario where `DoTheLogic` is invoking `DoTheLogic1` and which calls `DoTheLogic2` whre `DoTheLogic` transforms the object to a new object required by `DotTheLogic1` an invoke it; So in this case `DoTheLogic` is working completely as pure function and works on parameter passed even while invoking the downstream methods.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3) is context of Azure function project which uses dependency injection. You can see [Startup.cs](https://github.com/amigup/CleanArchitecture-For-AzureFunctionV3/blob/master/CleanArchitecture.Functions/Startup.cs) to understand how DI is setup and ILogger is injected into `ToDoItemsService`.